# Controller method does not updates data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have this form group:

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="status">
   @if((auth()->user()->two_factor_auth) === 'off')
   <option value="off">Off</option>
   <option value="sms">SMS</option>
   @else
   <option value="off">Off</option>
   <option value="sms">SMS</option>
   @endif
</select>
```

And as the action, I added this to the method `submit` of `ProfileController`:

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    if($data['status'] === 'off'){
        $request->user()->update([
            'two_factor_auth' => 'off'
        ]);
    }else{...}
}
```

And then at the DB,`users` table, I have added `two_factor_auth` column and it is set to `sms` by default.

So if the user selects, `off`, it should update the column and set `off`. But now the problem is it does not do that somehow...

So what is going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sidenote, you have the same `<option>`s in the `if` and `else` statements, which means as written, it is currently pointless. Is one of those supposed to be `on`? You can also move the `SMS` option out of that `@if` so you don't have to write it twice.

Comment: Next, `$data['status']` is not how you access that; it's `$request->input('status')`. Currently, `$data` is not defined in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html need to be replaced, add the `selected` attribute to the option you find in your DB/object

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="status">
   @if((auth()->user()->two_factor_auth) === 'off')
   <option selected value="off">Off</option>
   <option value="sms">SMS</option>
   @else
   <option value="off">Off</option>
   <option selected value="sms">SMS</option>
   @endif
</select>
```

You can also do in in just two lines

```
@php
$isOff = auth()->user()->two_factor_auth === 'off';
@endphp
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="status">
   <option @if($isOff) selected @endif value="off">Off</option>
   <option @if(!$isOff) selected @endif value="sms">SMS</option>
</select>
```

As for the controller, maybe you did not post all the code, but try this

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    //you should add validation rules here
    $user = auth()->user();
    $user->status = $request->input('status', 'sms');//second attribute is for default
    //you can add other attributes to update here 
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: Alternative syntax; I find `<option {{ $isOff ? 'selected' : '' }}>`  or `<option {{ !isOff ? 'selected' : '' }}>` cleaner than an inline `@if ... @endif` (both work just fine though)

Comment: @TimLewis it's does the same thing but using @if removes the `else` statement.

Comment: Ah yeah, fair enough point; and the `: ''` portion of the ternary serves no purpose here. Like I said, either or is fine :)